# Unable to activate a sheet in workbook using addin

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

i used the below code in add-in:

```
Sub MacroToRunOne()

Dim S As String
S = "Hello World From One:"
MsgBox S

Workbooks("86750").Sheets("PIVOT").Activate

End Sub
```

when i'm running this macro by I'm getting an error: "Subscript out of range" after the msgbox statement. is There some problem with my activate statement or is it not the way to code it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the activate statement? Is workbook 86750 the workbook from which the macro is in?

Comment: Yes... It's a workbook

Comment: well if it's the workbook you're working with, you'd be better off using     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PIVOT").Activate

Comment: No @SamWard that will not work as i'm using add-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the workbook with the filename`"86750"` (no extension), which does not exist.

Did you mean to put, `Workbooks("86750.xlsx")` , which would refer to the (open) workbook with the filename `86750.xlsx`.

Note that if you had provided a numeric argument, `i`, i.e. `Workbooks(86750)` you would be asking for the `i`th workbook by index of all open workbooks. However this is not what you were doing.

Comment: There may even be a limit on the number of open workbooks - does anyone know if there is?

Comment: +1. Just to clarify, it's not so much an index issue, as a name issue. It didn't work because the code was looking for a workbook called "86750" and failed because the extension was required. Trying `Workbooks("1")` will fail, even if there is one or more workbooks open, whereas  `Workbooks(1)` will work. Similarly  `Workbooks("JustinDavies")` will fail, whereas `Workbooks("JustinDavies.xlsx")` will work.  <br/>I think the workbook limit is subject to memory. Nice bike!